# BLAZOR NET CORE 3.x (Render problem from codebehind)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

tengo un componente blazor, que contiene una grilla con un boton!  (CORE 3.x). El boton tiene un EventCallBack para luego poder capturar el click desde el componente padre. Esto funciona ok, el problema es que estoy queriendo realizar esta misma accion desde el codebehind (Con RenderTreeBuilder, heredando de ComponentBase).

Este es el codigo que funciona en el componente .razor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo realizar el evento @click desde el backend?? 
Probe esto pero no funciona: 
builder.AddAttribute(localSequence, "onclick", "(e => OnClickGridButton(e))")

Comment: Estás en Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor edita tu pregunta o bórrala y ponla en el sitio en Inglés.

Comment: Cambiado! gracias